# Is there an R function like cor() but for true positives?

Tags: r, function

I have a dataset such as the one below:

```
  A B C D
1 1 0 0 1
2 0 0 1 1
3 1 1 1 1
4 1 0 1 1
```

and I would like to create a matrix of "true positives" (or instances where both variables have a 1) between every pair of variables. cor() creates this matrix quite nicely for correlations - I'm wondering if there's something similar for true positives?

Edit to show example of desired output:

```
   A B C D
A  3 1 2 3
B  1 3 1 1
C  2 1 3 3
D  3 1 3 3
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, could you show your desired output for that sample input?

Comment: *Both* variables?  You appear to have four...

Comment: @GregorThomas Just added the desired output

Comment: @Limey My actual data has 150 variables. I said both because I'm looking for a matrix of pairwise comparisons

Comment: I get different results in the [2,2] and [4,4] position (as does @G.Grothendieck).  Are those correct, and if  so can you explain how they're computed? (I assume that the number of matches between a column and itself = `sum(c*c) == sum(c==1) == sum(c)` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to matrix if it is not already a matrix and then use `crossprod` to multiply its transpose times itself.

```
crossprod(as.matrix(d))
```

giving:

```
  A B C D
A 3 1 2 3
B 1 1 1 1
C 2 1 3 3
D 3 1 3 4
```

### Note

```
d <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), B = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
    C = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), D = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```r
d <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
m <- diag(colSums(d==1))
## count (1,1) pairs
lt <- combn(1:ncol(d),2,FUN=function(x) sum(d[,x[1]]*d[,x[2]]))
## fill in values
m[lower.tri(m)] <- lt   
## make symmetric
m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    1    2    3
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    2    1    3    3
[4,]    3    1    3    4
```

With 150 variables this will involve `choose(150,2)==11175` separate computations, which could be a bit slow but is not necessarily infeasible.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function:

```
cor_mat <- function(x){
  result <- diag(colSums(df))
  d <- combn(data.frame(x), 2, function(y)sum(y[,1]*y[,2]))
  result[lower.tri(result)] <- d
  result[upper.tri(result)] <- t(result)[upper.tri(result)]
  result
}


cor_mat(df)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    1    2    3
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    2    1    3    3
[4,]    3    1    3    4
```

Comment: almost identical to mine! `combn(data.frame(x), ...)` is  a nice touch

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication. Returns same result as the other two less efficient approaches offered so far.

t(m) %*% m